# jQuery validation plugin and ajax post before validating the input

Tags: jquery, validation

Hello guys I'm trying to implement some username check form with validation plugin.

So I've tried this but this is not working.

```
rules: {
    username: {
      minlength: 4,
      required: {
        depends: function(element){
            $.get('/assets/system/ajax/username_check.php', {username:element.value}, function(data){
                if(data==1){
                  return true;
                } else {
                  return false; 
            }
         });
       }
    },
 }, ...
```

What I'm trying to do is the username input is required but if username not available do not validate it.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A29LE/

Comment: dude, is it possible to provide with a jsfiddle link.

Comment: here you go, http://jsfiddle.net/A29LE/

Comment: what's the problem then?

Comment: actually im trying to manually set the input valid or invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add Validator Method for this to work.

Validator Method :

```
$.validator.addMethod("checkUsername", 
    function(value, element) {
        var result = false;
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            async: false,
            url: "/assets/system/ajax/username_check.php",
            data: {username: value},
            success: function(data) {
                result = (data == "1") ? true : false;
            }
        });
        return result;
    }, 
    "Username Already Exists."
);
```

Modify your rule :

```
    rules: {
        "username": {
            minlength: 4,
            required: true,
            checkUsername: true
        },
    }
```

Hopefully this help.

More info about addMethod : [http://jqueryvalidation.org](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/)

Comment: oh boy, you are amazing. probably my months are saved. thank you so much!